# Partial date picker in angular 7

Tags: angular, date, datepicker, angular7, partial

I'm using angular 7 and I'm Searching for a component that can support partial date
I need some date picker that the user can choose only year or year and month or year month and day (full day)
for example, if the user wants to choose only year:

[image: two muppets]

I tried to search in angular material but I didn't find anything.

Does anyone know such a component?

Thanks!

Comment: Datepicker from angular Material can be customize as you want. Just have look at `DateAdapter `. See more at https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview section `Choosing a date implementation and date format settings`

Answer (score 1):

I think Angular Material is your go to, there are many options to make it work you're way.
This is just an sample of how you can do it. Everything comes from the documentation: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date" [formControl]="date" > 
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker  
    startView="multi-year"
    [startAt]="startDate"
    (yearSelected)="chosenYearHandler($event)"
    (monthSelected)="chosenMonthHandler($event, dp)">
  </mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

and the functions

```
    date = new FormControl(new Date());

  chosenYearHandler(Year) {   
    this.date.setValue(Year);
  }
  chosenMonthHandler(Month) {
    this.date.setValue(Month);
  }
```

I recommend you read the documentation again and rethink the options you can do with the datepicker. Good luck!

Comment: I found this example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mulitdate-picker-demo
But what I need it one picker that combine all three of them. so user can choose a year and accept, or year and month or full date.

Comment: When you click year in my example, it stores the clicked year you can close the picker. The same for month first you pick year then you pick month and the year and month gets saved. You only have to make a button to close it.